# What the sentence is saying (mean)

Tags: meaning

" Whoever is a socialite is vain."

I need a description/explanation to what the sentence is saying.

*The sentence isn't a part of a paragraph or something, it is just a single sentence without a context.

Comment: whoever pronoun (ANYONE) **any person who** [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/whoever)

Comment: What @MichaelHarvey said. Note that although the cited text is syntactically valid, it's not very idiomatic - nearly all native speakers in nearly all contexts would express this assertion as ***Anyone who** is a socialite is vain* (or perhaps ***All** socialites are vain*).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [socialite](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/socialite) is an extraverted person.

Someone who is [vain](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/vain) cares a lot about their public image and personal appearance.

"Whoever is X is Y." is a sentence construction meaning that all the people who are X (socialites) are also Y (vain). The opposite does not necessarily have to hold; not all vain people need to be socialites.